# Need two different counts between two adjacent cells compared with two criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I need result available in result column in MS excel. The input data is depicted below. In first row, there are **3** X columns(X1,X2,X3...) cells contains "Req" and its associated **2** Y cells(Y1, Y2, Y3...) Y1, Y2 contains values. X3 has "Req" but no value in Y3. That is why, in result column it has been flagged **1 out of 3 required**. X4 has Glove but there is no "Req" prefixed. Mean not required.

```
X1     | Y1   | X2    | Y2     | X3    | Y3| X4   | Y4| X5| Y5| Result
Req-BX |BOX   |Req-EA |EACH    |Req-CA |   |Glove |   |   |   | 1 out of 3 Required
Req-BT |BOTTLE|Req-GL |        |Req-CTN|   |      |   |   |   | 2 out of 3 Required
```

I have columns till X50,Y50. Please help.

Comment: Hey @shiva, interesting problem. Two quick questions: (1) Do you have 50 columns [meaning cell AX50 is the last one] or 50 rows that that are formatted like your example [meaning cell Y50 is the last one]? (2) Have you tried any VBA or formulas to solve the problem?

Comment: (1) Dan it is 50 columns headers like X1,Y1, X2, Y2 ...X50,Y50 and I have 500 rows to flag in Result column (2) I tried =COUNTIF(G2:CT2,"*Req*") formula to obtain counts having clause "Req" from X1 to X50 i.e. G2 to CT2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this VBA out:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Stack()

Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, _
    ResultCol As Long, RowIdx As Long, _
    ColIdx As Long, ReqCounter As Long, _
    FoundCounter As Long

'assign sheet for easy reference
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'define the range for our loops
LastRow = 500
LastCol = 75 'column CT
ResultCol = 76 'column CU

'loop through target rows
For RowIdx = 2 To LastRow

    'initialize counters
    ReqCounter = 0
    FoundCounter = 0

    'loop through target columns
    For ColIdx = 1 To LastCol Step 2

        'check to see if the cell contains "Req" and increment as necessary
        If InStr(1, DataSheet.Cells(RowIdx, ColIdx), "Req", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ReqCounter = ReqCounter + 1
        End If

        'check the neighboring cell for a non-blank value and increment as necessary
        If DataSheet.Cells(RowIdx, ColIdx + 1).Value <> "" Then
            FoundCounter = FoundCounter + 1
        End If

    Next ColIdx

    'write to the result cell
    DataSheet.Cells(RowIdx, ResultCol) = FoundCounter & " out of " & ReqCounter & " Required"

Next RowIdx
Msgbox ("Script complete!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. This worked exactly as I required with a small modification. I had to put second If statement inside the First If statement.

Comment: Glad to hear it @Shiva!